# Delete file after staring connection using FileInputStream

Tags: java, playframework, inputstream

I have a temporary file which I want to send the client from the controller in the Play Framework. Can I delete the file after opening a connection using FileInputStream? For example can I do something like this -

```
File file = getFile();
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
file.delete();
renderBinary(is, "name.txt");
```

What if file is a large file? If I delete the file, will subsequent reads() on InputStream give an error? I have tried with files of around 1MB I don't get an error.

Sorry if this is a very naive question, but I could not find anything related to this and I am pretty new to Java

Comment: Maybe it will be safer to set some scheduled task which will delete temporary files older than let's say 60 minutes? Just wondering.

Comment: @biesior that was I ended up doing. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this exact same scenario in some code I was asked to work on. The programmer was creating a temp file, getting an input stream on it, deleting the temp file and then calling renderBinary. It seems to work fine even for very large files, even into the gigabytes.

I was surprised by this and am still looking for some documentation that indicates why this works.

UPDATE: We did finally encounter a file that caused this thing to bomb. I think it was over 3 Gb. At that point, it became necessary to NOT delete the file while the rendering was in process. I actually ended up using the Amazon Queue service to queue up messages for these files. The messages are then retrieved by a scheduled deletion job. Works out nicely, even with clustered servers on a load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems counter-intuitive that the FileInputStream can still read after the file is removed.

[DiskLruCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/disklrucache/DiskLruCache.java), a popular library in the Android world originating from the [libcore](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.1.1_r1/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/DiskLruCache.java) of the Android platform, even relies on this "feature", as follows:

```
// Open all streams eagerly to guarantee that we see a single published
// snapshot. If we opened streams lazily then the streams could come
// from different edits.
InputStream[] ins = new InputStream[valueCount];
try {
  for (int i = 0; i < valueCount; i++) {
    ins[i] = new FileInputStream(entry.getCleanFile(i));
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
....
```

As @EJP pointed out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911259/fileinputstream-still-can-be-read-while-source-file-deleted#comment38727555_24911259) on a similar question, "That's how Unix and Linux behave. Deleting a file is really deleting its name from the directory: the inode and the data persist while any processes have it open."

But I don't think it is a good idea to rely on it.