# FileInputStream still can be read while source file deleted

Tags: java, android, file-upload, file-io, locked-files

I have encountered a very strange problem in android:

In my app, i will upload files from cache directory. If a user uses cleaner app like cleanmaster to clear my app's cache directory while my app uploading files, all files got deleted, but the uploading tasks don't stop at all and will complete successfully later without losing any data. Moreover, while these "no source file task" still uploading,
i can not access the cache directory any more, e.g. if i want to create a new file in the cache directory, i get 'ebusy' error.

my app use FileInputStream to open, read data form file in the upload task like this：

```
InputSream in = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
int bytes;
while ((bytes = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    netOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
}
in.close();
```

I assume the system has cached the file while opened by FileInputStream, how can i disable caching? What i want is: if file deleted, reading from stream throw error and my uploading task stop.

My questions:

1. Why FileInputSream still can be read while source file deleted
2. Why the cache diretory is locked, by who?
3. Any solution to my case?

Comment: How big are these files? Maybe the task is finished by the time you run the cleaner app

Comment: @jaytj95 average size is 20MB, and i am sure files still uploading after cleaning through progress log.

Comment: That's how Unix and Linux behave. Deleting a file is really deleting its name from the directory: the `inode` and the data persist while any processes have it open.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, so it means a file is not actually deleted until all opening handles close? But why the directory being locked?