# Android Totalcmd Wrong delete!Delete to trash how to restore a deleted file (totalcmd)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

I need to recover a video file I accidentally deleted.

Help me I suddenly delete the wrong video file. Are there any plugins for totalcmd like back2life to recover the file?

My Phone is an android 10 not rooted and not unlocked.

Can this save me？
https://www.firstpost.com/tech/news-analysis/android-11-might-come-with-a-hidden-recycle-bin-feature-to-let-trash-files-instead-of-deleting-them-8493351.html/amp

A report by 9to5 Google says that the new feature is quite similar to the Recycle Bin on Windows computers, except Android won’t have a dedicated trash folder to show your trashed items.

A glimpse of this feature was provided by app developer Yuriy Mysochenko in February. Mysochenko used the first Android 11 Developer Preview that h

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883839/how-to-list-recently-deleted-files-from-a-directory And i find this
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92816/can-a-file-be-retrieved-by-its-inode
If totalcmd use delete inode to delete file
Any possible ways to recovery file by recreate former file inode
Did totalcmd saved the deleted file's inode information?or Android system have that

Comment: And one said "I'm not sure if there's a way to output all the filenames, but you can retrieve the contents of a file with the cat command. Like this, cat <32611>, replacing the number with the inode you want to check. – nextstep Aug 7 '15 at 20:23 @nextstep

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911259/fileinputstream-still-can-be-read-while-source-file-deleted     That's how Unix and Linux behave. Deleting a file is really deleting its name from the directory: the inode and the data persist while any processes have it open